# Check all the Select of same class are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if all the dropdown of same class are selected means the selected val should not be `Select Subject` for the specified class `DD_Sub` in each condition  the problem is say if all the dropdown has selected value  `Select Subject` then it alerts to select the option but if any one of DD value is changed though the remaining still it contains the value `Select Subject` then also it says all selected that should not happen.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/shaikasifpasha3/vjtpd4vx/1/#&togetherjs=fIsDmsKDm6

**HTML:**

```
<select class="DD_Sub" >
    <option value="Select Subject">  Select Subject  </option>
    <option value="Holiday">  Holiday  </option>
    <option value="Lunch">  Lunch  </option>
    <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select  class="DD_Sub" >
    <option value="Select Subject">  Select Subject  </option>
    <option value="Holiday">  Holiday  </option>
    <option value="Lunch">  Lunch  </option>
    <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select class="DD_Sub" >
    <option value="Select Subject">  Select Subject  </option>
    <option value="Holiday">  Holiday  </option>
    <option value="Lunch">  Lunch  </option>
    <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Click Me" onclick="return CheckDD();" id="BodyHolder_Add_New_period_button">
```

**JS:**

```
 function CheckDD() {
     // The .each() method is unnecessary here:
     $(".DD_Sub").each(function() {
         if ($(this).val() == "Select Subject") {
             alert("Select Subject");
             return false;
         } else {
             alert("All Selected");
             return false;
         }

     });
 }
```

Comment: "Select Subject" should be alerted if all selected options have "Select Subject" selected ?

Comment: No Select Subject Should be alerted if any one of the DD option selected `Select Subject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function CheckDD() {
  if ($(".DD_Sub option:selected[value='Select Subject']").length > 0) {
    alert('Select Subject');   
  }
  else {
    alert('All Selected');
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hear you goo http://jsfiddle.net/shaikasifpasha3/vjtpd4vx/1/#&togetherjs=fIsDmsKDm6

Comment: I'd suggest `$(".DD_Sub option:selected[value='Select Subject']").length > 0` to be sure.

Comment: @rainerh Can you help me out i have some issue i think u can sort it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719544/delete-only-check-box-checked-columns-from-html-table

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.get()` , `Array.prototype.every()`

```js
function CheckDD() {

  // The .each() method is unnecessary here:
  $(".DD_Sub").get().every(function(el) {

    return $("option:selected", el).val() == "Select Subject"

  }) ? alert("All Selected") : alert("Select Subject");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="DD_Sub">
  <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
  <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
  <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
  <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>



</select>
<br/>
<select class="DD_Sub">
  <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
  <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
  <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
  <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>



</select>
<br/>
<select class="DD_Sub">
  <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
  <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
  <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
  <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>



</select>


<input type="submit" value="Click Me" onclick="return CheckDD();" id="BodyHolder_Add_New_period_button">
```

Comment: No i need the rivers of this what u have done is if all has the value select subject it says all selected it should not say nutill all the dd has different value then select subject

Comment: @Shaik See updated post , substituted `.every()` for `.some()`

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
 function CheckDD() {
     // state of validation - true by default
     var allValid = true;
     $(".DD_Sub").each(function () {
         // check if value was selected
         if ($(this).val() == "Select Subject") {
             alert("Select Subject");
             // if value is not selected set state to false
             allValid = false;
             return false;
         }
     });
     // display success only if state is true
     if (allValid === true) {
         alert("All Selected");
     }
     //return the result
     return allValid;
 }
```

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mk1t2okf/1/)

Comment: Thanks your code to works exactly as i wanted again thanks for ur support

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.DD_Sub option[value="Select Subject"]').is(':selected')){
    alert('Select Subject');
} else {
    alert('All Selected');
}
```