# Delete Only check box checked Columns From HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to delete the check box checked HTML column But now on delete click the last column is getting deleted what i want is on delete Click all the check box checked columns should be deleted

and on add period click my table gets auto increment

[JS Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaikasifpasha3/Lvsfcb4w/1/)

HTML:

```
<table border="1" id="TimeTable_Table" style="       margin-left: 1%; border-collapse: collapse;   text-align: left; width:98%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Days</td>
            <td>Period 1</td>
            <th>Period 2</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="ctl00$BodyHolder$tb1" type="text" value="Monday" readonly="readonly" id="BodyHolder_tb1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_Sub1" id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub1" class="DD_Sub" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
                    <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                    <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                    <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                    <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
                    <option value="ECO-22">ECO-22</option>

                </select>
                <br>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_TName1" id="BodyHolder_DD_TName1" class="DD_TName" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
           <option value="Select Teacher">Select Teacher</option>
                    <option value="No Class">No Class</option>
                    <option value="FTPW40">ArunKumar. K</option>
                    <option value="FTPW46">Asha Rani.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW48">Ashwini.V Bhat</option>
                    <option value="FTPW11">B.C.Shiva Kumar</option>
                    <option value="FTPW53">Chandrashekar K.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW36">Chandru. E</option>
                    <option value="FTPW54">Lokesh.C.S</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_Sub1" id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub1" class="DD_Sub" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
                             <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                    <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                    <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                    <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
                    <option value="ECO-22">ECO-22</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_TName1" id="BodyHolder_DD_TName1" class="DD_TName" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
       <option value="Select Teacher">Select Teacher</option>
                    <option value="No Class">No Class</option>
                    <option value="FTPW40">ArunKumar. K</option>
                    <option value="FTPW46">Asha Rani.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW48">Ashwini.V Bhat</option>
                    <option value="FTPW11">B.C.Shiva Kumar</option>
                    <option value="FTPW53">Chandrashekar K.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW36">Chandru. E</option>
                    <option value="FTPW54">Lokesh.C.S</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="ctl00$BodyHolder$TextBox1" type="text" value="Tuesday" readonly="readonly" id="BodyHolder_TextBox1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_Sub2" id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub2" class="DD_Sub" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
                            <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                    <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                    <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                    <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
                    <option value="ECO-22">ECO-22</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_TName2" id="BodyHolder_DD_TName2" class="DD_TName" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
       <option value="Select Teacher">Select Teacher</option>
                    <option value="No Class">No Class</option>
                    <option value="FTPW40">ArunKumar. K</option>
                    <option value="FTPW46">Asha Rani.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW48">Ashwini.V Bhat</option>
                    <option value="FTPW11">B.C.Shiva Kumar</option>
                    <option value="FTPW53">Chandrashekar K.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW36">Chandru. E</option>
                    <option value="FTPW54">Lokesh.C.S</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_Sub2" id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub2" class="DD_Sub" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
          <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                    <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                    <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                    <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
                    <option value="ECO-22">ECO-22</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_TName2" id="BodyHolder_DD_TName2" class="DD_TName" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
       <option value="Select Teacher">Select Teacher</option>
                    <option value="No Class">No Class</option>
                    <option value="FTPW40">ArunKumar. K</option>
                    <option value="FTPW46">Asha Rani.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW48">Ashwini.V Bhat</option>
                    <option value="FTPW11">B.C.Shiva Kumar</option>
                    <option value="FTPW53">Chandrashekar K.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW36">Chandru. E</option>
                    <option value="FTPW54">Lokesh.C.S</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_TName2" id="BodyHolder_DD_TName2" class="DD_TName" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
       <option value="Select Teacher">Select Teacher</option>
                    <option value="No Class">No Class</option>
                    <option value="FTPW40">ArunKumar. K</option>
                    <option value="FTPW46">Asha Rani.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW48">Ashwini.V Bhat</option>
                    <option value="FTPW11">B.C.Shiva Kumar</option>
                    <option value="FTPW53">Chandrashekar K.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW36">Chandru. E</option>
                    <option value="FTPW54">Lokesh.C.S</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="ctl00$BodyHolder$TextBox2" type="text" value="Wednesday" readonly="readonly" id="BodyHolder_TextBox2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_Sub3" id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub3" class="DD_Sub" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
            <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                    <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                    <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                    <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
                    <option value="ECO-22">ECO-22</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_TName3" id="BodyHolder_DD_TName3" class="DD_TName" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
               <option value="Select Teacher">Select Teacher</option>
                    <option value="No Class">No Class</option>
                    <option value="FTPW40">ArunKumar. K</option>
                    <option value="FTPW46">Asha Rani.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW48">Ashwini.V Bhat</option>
                    <option value="FTPW11">B.C.Shiva Kumar</option>
                    <option value="FTPW53">Chandrashekar K.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW36">Chandru. E</option>
                    <option value="FTPW54">Lokesh.C.S</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_Sub3" id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub3" class="DD_Sub" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
             <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                    <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                    <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                    <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
                    <option value="ECO-22">ECO-22</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_TName3" id="BodyHolder_DD_TName3" class="DD_TName" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
         <option value="Select Teacher">Select Teacher</option>
                    <option value="No Class">No Class</option>
                    <option value="FTPW40">ArunKumar. K</option>
                    <option value="FTPW46">Asha Rani.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW48">Ashwini.V Bhat</option>
                    <option value="FTPW11">B.C.Shiva Kumar</option>
                    <option value="FTPW53">Chandrashekar K.S</option>
                    <option value="FTPW36">Chandru. E</option>
                    <option value="FTPW54">Lokesh.C.S</option>
                </select>
            </td>

        </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>

           </td>


           <td>
               <input type="checkbox"/>
           </td>


           <td>
               <input type="checkbox"/>
           </td>
    </tbody>
</table>

                <input type="submit" value="Add Period" onclick="return addcourse();" id="BodyHolder_Add_New_period_button">
                     <input type="submit" value="Delete Period's" onclick="return Delete_Column();" id="BodyHolder_Add_New_period_button">
```

JS:

```
function addcourse() {



 var newHeader = $('#TimeTable_Table thead tr').append('<th></th>');
                $('#TimeTable_Table').find('th:last()').append('Period ' + ($('#TimeTable_Table thead tr th').length + 1));
                $.each($('#TimeTable_Table tbody').find('tr'), function (i, v) {
                    $(v).append($(v).find('td:last()').clone());
                });
}


function Delete_Column() {

var Cell_Length =document.getElementById('TimeTable_Table').rows[0].cells.length;
    if(Cell_Length =="2")
    {
    alert("This Row Should Not be Deleted");
    }
    else
    {

    $('#TimeTable_Table tr').find('th:last-child, td:last-child').remove();

    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add that to plunkr? Would be easier to help